# Various ways to specify JDK version for a Kotlin project in Gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In various answers I found the following ways to specify the JDK version:

```kotlin
const val JDK_VERSION = 17

// 1
extensions.configure<KotlinMultiplatformExtension> {
    jvm {
        jvmToolchain(JDK_VERSION)
    }
}

// 2
tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java) {
    compilerOptions {
        jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.fromTarget(JDK_VERSION.toString()))
    }
}

// 3
extensions.findByType(JavaPluginExtension::class.java)?.apply {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion(JDK_VERSION)
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion(JDK_VERSION)
}
```

Can you please tell me what is the difference between them all? In what cases should they be used?

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/11/gradle-jvm-toolchain-support-in-the-kotlin-plugin/